# Create Symbolic Links rather than copy files

Tags: batch-file, symlink, robocopy

So, I'm running a batch file on Windows 10 that copies files and compresses them with 7-zip. I'm trying to make the batch file run quickly, and 7-zip and some other programs I use do seem to pick up on Symbolic Links. What I want to do is use Robocopy to clone the directory and exclude certain folders, and then have the symbolic links created to the original files, while excluding certain file types. Here is the Robocopy command I used to copy the files originally, I basically want to replicate it but have it or another command create symbolic links instead of copy files.

```
robocopy %proj% "!expt!\%os%\Game\www" /E /W:1 /XF *.m4a *.rpgproject /XD save
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Herrmann Schinagl's `ln.exe` ([here](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/ln/ln.html)) does exactly what you are trying to do - compare, link identical files and copy different ones. All intricate details of symlinks, inner and outer joins are explained with illustrations. The 'DeLorean Copy' should be just the right method.